# Adding columns to array pscustomobject

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm creating an array and attempting to add columns.  However, I'm not always getting the correct results in the Connected column.  It seems like the nested if/elses aren't working.

I threw in TEST.exe as a test.  It is a non-existent process.

```
#Build array List of .Exe(s) to make sure is running.
$Exearray = @("tws", "Autotrader", "iqconnect", "TEST")

$result =  $Exearray  | ForEach-Object {

    $Connected = ""
    $twsloginfail = ""
    $running = "" 
    $Notrunning = ""
    $processstart = ""
    $process = Get-Process -Name $PSItem -IncludeUserName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $process)
    {
        $Notrunning = "Yes"
        $s = $Error[0].Exception.Message 
        $separator = "." 
        $msg = $s.split($separator)
        $message = $msg[0]
    }
    if ($process)
    {

        #Check if a process named "$PSItem.exe" is running
        $running = "Yes" 
        $process = Get-Process -Name $PSItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $processstart = $process.starttime


            #Logfile of user
            $IQlogfile = Get-Content "C:\Users\user0\Documents\DTN\IQFeed\IQConnectLog.txt" -Tail 2 | where { ($_ -match '\bConnected\b') } #and connected needed

        #Uniquely Identify Connected status on line
         if ($PSItem -eq "iqconnect")
        {
        #Successful IQFeed
        $Connected = "IQConnected"
        }
        else
        {
        #Add IQFeed Connection error to body.
        $Connected = ""
        }



        #Check for tws Login Failed text document
$loginFailFrequency = "C:\Jts\loginFailFrequency.txt"
$twsloginfail = Test-Path $loginFailFrequency
     if ($PSItem -eq "tws")
    {
        #File exists
       $Connected = ""
    }
    else
    {
        #Successful IB TWS
$Connected = "IBKRConnected"
    }

        
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Software = $PSItem + ".exe"
        Connected = $Connected
        Message = $message
        starttime = $processstart
        Running = $running
        NotRunning = $Notrunning
    }
}


$result
```

[image: Results]
Any help or tips is appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, i suggest you to always specify in the post what WAS the EXPECTED outcome EXACTLY.
In this case it's easy to understand by reading the script, but it's always better to make sure without needing to read the code.

That said: Yeah the problem is in the IFs: they way you wrote the code it will ALWAYS return empty for `tws.exe` and ALWAYS return `IBKRConnected` for any other running process.
And you completely missed the point of $PSItem: it does NOT ret replaced by the content of the last command. In your script remains the value of the iteration of the items in `$Exearray`

for example:

```
    #Check for tws Login Failed text document
    $loginFailFrequency = 'C:\Jts\loginFailFrequency.txt'
    $twsloginfail = Test-Path $loginFailFrequency
    if ($PSItem -eq 'tws') {
        #File exists
        $Connected = ''
    }
    else {
        #Successful IB TWS
        $Connected = 'IBKRConnected'
    }
```

`$PSItem` here is STILL referring to the looping iteration of `$Exearray` NOT the result of `Test-Path`. Same, I'm going to guess, for the previous `if ($PSItem -eq 'iqconnect')`: `$PSItem` was NOT referring to the contents of `IQlogfile` but still the iteration of `$Exearray`.

In general your script has a few issues:

Why `if(-not $process){...} if($process){...}` instead of `if(-not process){...} else{...}`?

Why having both `$Running` AND `$NotRunning`? One variable with Yes\No(or $True$False though that would depend on your use-case) would be better.

Why a second `Get-process` with the same values? You still have the previous result. It's completely useless, though I guess it's caused by your misunderstanding of `$PSItem` and\or scope?

Minor: unless you specifically need empty lines, you don't need to create variable in advance with empty values. If you try to load a variable that has not been defined before in another variable(or in this case an object's property) it will simply automagically be converted into a `$null` value which is usually good enough (again:depends on your specific needs)

Comment: Thank you for the extra set of eyes sirtao.  The if/elses' have been corrected as you pointed out!. I appreciate your time.
Iceman